# OpenType embedded SVG rendered slightly too small in Firefox

Tags: svg, typography, opentype

I created a very small True Type font with a simple square as the only glyph at char code 0xe000. It is included both as a standard glyph and as an SVG in the 'SVG ' table, as defined in the [SVG Glyphs in OpenType Specification](https://www.w3.org/2013/10/SVG_in_OpenType/)

The problem is that the SVG glyph is rendered about 2% smaller on Firefox than the TrueType glyph, although it should have the same size. The size of the TrueType glyph is the correct one.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbhn4q01/) (font size 240px with the background set to cyan) and this is the output on Firefox (left) and on Chrome (identical on IE11 and Edge14)

[image]

I have tried the same with other, more complex shapes. Each time the SVG is a little bit smaller than the standard glyph.

Does anybody know if this is the indended or specified behaviour (embedded SVG must be 2% larger to render the same size)? Or is this simply a bug in Firefox and I should issue a bug report? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Detailed Information about the SVG and the Font**

This is the SVG:

```
<svg id="glyph2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1024" height="1024"><g fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><g><path d="M256,-640l512,0l0,512l-512,0z"/></g></g></svg>
```

The glyph data in the font#s "glyf" table looks like this:

[image]

Here is the data from the font's "hhea" table:

[image]

The test font can be donwloaded from http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45977357366223472123

Comment: Edge 14 renders the SVG the same size as the standard glyph, so it really looks like a bug in Firefox. I have opened an bugzilla issue at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1320197